# C++, pass a function of n arguments as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, parameters, arguments

Let us suppose that we have a function of n variables

```
y = f (x1, ..., xn)
```

Such a function I would like to pass as an argument.

In Matlab the following construction using a handle is available:

```
function y=func(x)
y = sin(x(0)) * cos(x(1))  //Any definition, not important

p_func=@func; //Define handle
```

It is possible to use the handle as a parameter of another function:

```
y = function2(p_func, n);
```

where n represents a dimension...

How to rewrite this code using C++? We use a simple model with the function template

```
temmplate <typename T>
T func( const T *arg, const short n) {return sin(arg[0]) * cos(arg[1])};
```

where xi arguments are represented by the 1-dimensional array of n elements. The problem is that in this case it is not possible to use a pointer to the function template

```
template <class T>
static T ( *pfunc ) ( const T *arg, const short n )
```

only a specialization... Perhaps another model could be more appropriate...Thanks for your help...

**Remark:** 
I know that a class template is useful

```
template  <typename T>
class Foo
{ 
    T func( const T *args, const short n);
};
```

and this construction works:

```
template <class T>
static T ( *pfunc ) ( const T *arg, const short n )
```

But it may not be used in the current model of the library (I can not affect this).

Comment: "*But it may not be used in the current model of the library (I can not affect this).*" What specifically about this can't be used? Or more to the point, what are the exact limitations?

Comment: @Nicol: Limitations are given by the model of the library where I am adding code in. But I am afraid that I will have to do it :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is a *statically* typed language. Every object in C++, whether a function pointer, or whatever, must have a specific type. And the type of a function pointer is based on the types of arguments that the function to be pointed to is given.

A template is not an object, so you can't get a pointer to one. You can get a pointer to an *instantiation* of a template. Using your `func` definition, `func<int>` is a function that takes a `const int*` and a `short`. You can get a pointer to `func<int>`. But `func` is a template; you can't get a pointer to a template.

That's why C++ programs often throw functors around instead of function pointers. Functors can have a template `operator()` method, so you can call them as though you were passing around template functions. But since you say that you have to use a function pointer, there's not much that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is easily solved in C++, but there are approaches for similar cases. You should take a look at the [boost::bind and boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html) library. It was made for getting around the nasty details of passing function pointers around in C++ (and they allow to pass for class methods as well). As far as i recall they don't really use a generic N but instantiate templates for arbitrary N parameters. It's definitely worth a look if you want to get to something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the "n". The problem is the templated type T.

Are you trying to declare a variable (of type pointer to function), here?

```
template <class T>
static T ( *pfunc ) ( const T *arg, const short n )
```

This will not work without instantiating the template.

This is because of otherwise, type checking would be impossible. The type checker could not check if, when you initialized the pointer, T was the same as when you dereference it.

You will probably need to look at a bigger context. Where do you want to USE that declaration? Move the template parameter to that context.

For example, you could have a function, or class with template parameter T.
There, you could declare, initialize and dereference any function pointer which has T somewhere in it's type.

Maybe you can "bind" the parameters at the place where you assign the function pointer. So the resulting function will be a nullary function, which you can use without knowing the parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain pointer to template function, because template is not an object, it's just compile-time syntax construction producing multiple specific functions - **template instantiations**. Template instantiations, e.g. `f<int>(const int*, short)` are objects and can be pointed.

If you just want some simple and unified way to obtain function pointer from template instantiation, use `declspec()` (I'm supposing you are using modern C++11 compatible compiler):

```
template <class T> static T f(const T *, const short )
{
  // Implementation
  ...
}

// Declaring function pointers for int & double
typedef decltype(&f<int>) IntFuncPtr;
typedef decltype(&f<double>) DoubleFuncPtr;

// Sample usage
IntFuncPtr intFunc = &f<int>;
intFunc(NULL, 0);

DoubleFuncPtr doubleFunc = &f<double>;
doubleFunc(NULL, 0);
```